# Transform a list of elements into a comma separated sequence

Tags: xml, xslt

What I want to get is a XSLT template to turn several XML element values into a coma separated string to be the value of a single output element.

I have found several examples in tutorials to do so for **text** output, but nothing for XML output.

Sample input:

```
<People>
    <Person>John</Person>
    <Person>Paul</Person>
    <Person>George</Person>
    <Person>Ringo</Person>
</People>
```

Desired output:

```
<Output>
    <People>John,Paul,George,Ringo</People>
</Output>
```

This is what I got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:element name="Output">
                <xsl:element name="People">
                       <xsl:for-each select="People/Person">
                              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
         </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I don`t know how to get rid of the last coma using this approach. Any ideas?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short (1 template only) solution that is generic and doesn't rely on structural dependencies. It also doesn't use any explicit conditional logic instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<Output>
 <People>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="People/Person" />
 </People>
</Output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /><xsl:if test="following-sibling::Person">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: This will not produce CSV with quotes around each value.

Comment: Following sibling axe is better than multiple templates (but should be `following-sibling::Person` imho), OP should use this. Damn I've been away from XSL for too long.

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <People>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </People>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Person">
  <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(.,
            substring(',', 1 div not(position()=last()))
            )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<People>
    <Person>John</Person>
    <Person>Paul</Person>
    <Person>George</Person>
    <Person>Ringo</Person>
</People>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<People>John,Paul,George,Ringo</People>
```

**Do note**:

1. **No structural dependences are assumed** between the items in the sequence -- for example we do not use the fact that they are siblings.
2. **The above fact makes our transformation more generic** -- it can be used in situations where the items f the sequence are not siblings or even belong to more than one XML document.
3. **A clever XPath 1.0 trick helps avoid having different templates** for the first/last item and for the rest:

In XPath 1.0 `true()`,`false()` are converted to `1`,`0`.

`1 div 0`  is `positive-infinity` and `substring(anyString, 1, $x)` where `$x` is `positive-infinity`, is the complete string.